# Error after adding extensions to GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, gdal, extensions

I had installed java8, tomcat8.5.12, geoserver 2.9.4 in CentOS 6.9. I had added gdal libraries to the GeoServer from http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html.

I had restarted the tomcat there is no additional extensions added to the stores. Also, when I checked logs, I could see this:

```
it.geosolutions.imageio.gdalframework.gdal utilities load gdal failed to load the GDAL native libs.
this is not a problem unless you need to use the GDAL plugins:they wont be enabled.
```

I think it seems to be some path configuration error.

Comment: Did you also copy the jar file `From the javainfo directory in the archive, copy the imageio-ext-gdal-bindings-1.9.2.jar to the WEB-INF/lib directory of your GeoServer installation.`?

Comment: Yes i did it....

Comment: Did you get the exact version of the extension for your version of geoserver?

Comment: I am using geoserver 2.9.4. Which version of the extension suits?